# C# XNA - Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView - Extend how far camera can see

Tags: c#, xna, perspectivecamera

i am using the following code to setup my camera. I can see the elements in a range of some **100** fs. I want the camera to see farther.

```
projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((3.14159265f/10f), device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.2f, 40.0f);
```

**How to do it ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195665.aspx).

The last two parameters are the near and far plane distances. They determine the size of the view frustum associated with the camera. The view frustum looks like this:

[image]

Everything in the frustum is in the volume that the rasteriser uses for drawing - this includes a depth component. Everything outside this region is not drawn.

**Increase the distance of the far plane from the camera.**

But don't increase it further than you need to. The larger the distance between the near and far plane, the less resolution the Z-buffer has and the more likely you will see artefacts like Z-fighting.